# QWebChannel new client gets initial state?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebchannel

For better or worse I was exploring using QWebChannel as a method for creating networked video games. I've run into a problem where as new.clients join, they recieve the game state as it was originally, without any incremented changes that other clients have been making.

Looking at the [webchannel chat client example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-chatclient-qml-qmlchatclient-qml.html) it looks like the client links directly to the `changed` signals, and then pulls the properties directly using the method/property calls.

Does QWebChannel not incrementally update the state for new clients? Is there a way to work around this?

I currently have a property that is a `QVariantList` of QObects. Each QObject has an `enabled` property that gets updated. New clients are getting stale state and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post the code which causes you troubles.

Comment: It's going to be a little challenging since it's an entire code base. [Here's the C++](https://github.com/benhoff/qt5-cross-platform-apps/blob/master/core/gameinterface.h) side and [here's the QML side](https://github.com/benhoff/qt5-cross-platform-apps/blob/master/eatem/main.qml). I'm unsure how to break it into a concise question.

Comment: Looks like I need to be using [QQmlListProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) instead of QVariantList. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398932/running-into-issues-with-qvariantlists-and-qlists-of-custom-qobjects) helped guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt. It's been reported here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70078